# How to copy and paste changing origin values conditional upon which destination field i want them

Tags: microsoft-excel, copy-paste

In excel I have a set of data that changes daily, we'll call it "daily_data".

I need to copy and paste that data into the appropriate day of the week fields.  This is easy enough to do manually but I have several of these reports that I run on a daily basis.

I am trying to automate the process.

For example, I open the file and it shows me Monday's daily_data information. I want it to copy and paste that data into a static Monday field while leaving Tuesday through Friday empty. Then the following day it shows me Tuesday's daily_data.  I want it to copy into Tuesday's static field while leaving Wednesday through Friday alone. So now I can see Monday and Tuesday's data.  and hence forth through the rest of the week.  (I feel like I went overkill on the description. just trying to be clear).

It would save me a bunch of time if I could skip the step of copy and pasting all my daily_data fields into their appropriate day on a daily basis.

Comment: You can achieve this with a VBA macro that copies the values from the input column to a column selected depending on the current day of the week. Then just bind the macro to the open event.

Comment: I'd suggest VBa as well. However, we can't help because although the issue is clear and well explained, how the data is layed out is not clear. Can you add a screen shot of the daily_data tab and also the Monday field?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a VBA macro that copies the values from the input column to a column selected depending on the current day of the week. Then just bind the macro to the open event.

Let's hypothesize the layout shown here:

[image]

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    columnOffset = 2
    dow = Weekday(Now, vbMonday)
    col = dow + columnOffset
    ' If data already exists, don't do anything
    If Cells(2, col).Value = "" Then
        ' Copy the first column except the first cell
        Intersect(Columns(1), UsedRange.Offset(1)).Copy Cells(2, col)
    End If
End Sub
```